# Is there a more efficient way to keep track of parent records with no children?

Tags: mysql, sql

Part of the application that I'm working on is a "to-do list" that shows records that the users need to work on.  One of the set of criteria that needs to cause records to show up in this list is the absence of a corresponding record in another table.

From my reading and experimentation so far, there are three potential ways to accomplish this:

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.t1_id 
WHERE table2.t1_id IS NULL;

SELECT table1.id FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM table2 
WHERE table2.t1_id = table1.id);

SELECT table1.id FROM table1
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT table2.t1_id FROM table2);
```

I have seen various questions and answers about which one of these is more efficient, and depending on how I set up the indexes for the two tables in question, I can slightly alter that, although the LEFT JOIN seems to be the best overall.  But I think the tables are just too large for queries like this to be as quick as I need them to be.

My question is, is there ANY other way I might accomplish this more efficiently?  The only other solution I have come up with so far is to create another table that maps table1_id to zero or more table2_ids, with null values where there are no corresponding records in table2.  With an index on table2_id, the lookup I need is very fast; unfortunately I think this solution will be somewhat more difficult to manage.  Would this be a reasonable approach to take?

Comment: Did you verify that the approaches you mentioned are too slow to meet your requirements, or are you speculating?

Comment: It's also possible that RDBMS optimizer would convert them into each other.

Comment: Why do you need a third table? Can you add an integer column to table1 that keeps track of the number of related rows in table2? Maintaining it would require extra code. Does MySQL have triggers?

Comment: FYI, MySQL is notoriously bad at `exists` and `in` queries, as it will *often* recompute the subquery for each record in the outer query.  In general you should use the `join` approach instead.  (Some other DBMS, such as Oracle, do not suffer from this problem.)  If the join is still not fast enough you should consider storing the "this id still needs work" information in a table of its own.  Initialize it via your (slow) query just once, then update it via trigger whenever `table2` gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to find *all* records without a match in table2 faster than a LEFT JOIN, would be to cache the 'existence' of a row somewhere.  You mentioned a secondary table for this purpose, although adding an indexed boolean column on table1 would certainly be faster.

The problem with this approach are the same problems that always occurs when caching - namely:

- You need a way to ensure the integrity of this cache, and...
- Whatever method you use to ensure this integrity (triggers are a likely candidate), will require some overhead processing, and thus hurt performance for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on table2.

If these aren't problems for you, or are less of a problem than using a LEFT JOIN, then by all means - go ahead and do this.